# Mvc DropdownList Not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdownlistfor

**Issue Description:**

Dropdownlist after selection not showing the selected text from list.

[image]

Here I am using MVC Razor syntax to generate dropdownlist box.

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, 
                                  new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"),
                                  "---Select---", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)
    </div>
```

The list is correctly populating but after selecting the option it's not showing in the dropdownlist box.

Note: when I submit the form the correct selected value is sent to action.

**Steps checked:**

1. Checked the generated HTML it looks ok..

[image]

2. It uses bootstrap form-control class and the color set is Black. Also rest of the field values are displayed which are inside same form.
3. Browser computed tab
   [image]

Thanks in Advance..

update Solution:

I have defined some override for my form-control class for text spacing which caused the problem. 
I was thinking color was issue, but actually issue was with my text padding.

```
.form-control {
    font-size: 17px;
    /*padding: 20px 15px;*/  /*this statement caused issue*/
    border-radius: 9px; 
    height:42px; /* I replaced with padding to height which solved issue.*/
}
```

Comment: You html is generated correctly and posting back correctly so it suggests this is a css issue

Comment: I thought that it might be Css issue. Not sure way to find the overriding css. But I tried to add select#Genre.form-control.valid {
    color : black !important;
} 
it didnt work.

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the element and its styles

Comment: I did checked the computed tab as well. color is set to black.

Comment: Have you check there is no other element that might be masking it. And do you have any javascript/jquery?

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check that.. Since its a simple Html form with just 4 fields. Each under div with form-group class. for individual field I added form-control class. I dont see any over rides in form-control class for color.

Comment: You must have something else on the page causing it

Comment: How can I share my code?

Comment: Create a DotNetFiddle

Comment: Do you have bitbucket ? I can share my code

Comment: Found the issue. Its indeed css issue. in form-controlclass css definition, i have given padding: 20px 15px. And when I changed height: 42 px; the text are now showning after selection.

Comment: Unless your going to edit your question to show all the relevant information, and add your own answer to show how you solved it, this is not useful to anyone else, so you should delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined some override for my form-control class for text spacing which caused the problem. I was thinking color was issue, but actually issue was with my text padding.

```
.form-control {
    font-size: 17px;
    /*padding: 20px 15px;*/  /*this statement caused issue*/
    border-radius: 9px; 
    height:42px; /* I replaced with padding to height which solved issue.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry , I'm late.
But, the dropdownlist it works only as well, if you change the configuration to version PC on Tools in your tablet